# How to turn off IE10 Compatibility Mode for New Relic

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I've just started using New Relic.  It didn't display properly in IE9, so I installed IE10.  When I start the New Relic site, I am presented with the same display errors and the error message:

> We've noticed that you're running Internet Explorer in compatibility mode. The New Relic site works best with a modern browser. Please turn off compatibility mode for a better experience.

The display errors are that two columns of data are overlapped, the second one partially covering the first, and rendering both of them unreadable.

There's no Compatibility Mode button available in the address bar.  In the options, I can add sites to be displayed in Compatibility Mode, not prevent them from such.

How do I disable Compatibility Mode for the New Relic website in IE10?

Comment: When I opened the website today it looked correct.  Maybe I had a caching issue instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a button on the right side of the address bar, it looks like a ripped document:

[image]

When the button looks pressed, the site is rendered in compatibility mode:

[image]

I think the message on New Relic is wrong. They don’t even *allow* compatibility mode, because they have this snippet in their markup:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

This is why you don’t see the button: the tag forces IE to run in normal mode. You can check this for yourself: press <kbd>F12</kbd>, this open the developer tools. There you can see the exact current rendering mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I know the button you mean, I can see it on this page (Stack Exchange.)  Unfortunately it does not appear when I'm on the New Relic website.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food See my update.

Comment: Thanks for that!  When I opened the website today it looked correct.  Maybe I had a caching issue?  At least I'm confident I don't have Compatibility Mode erroneously turned on.  Thanks!